# Path works on desktop, but not mobile

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I've a tab bar on a responsive app I'm building:

```html
<template name="tabNav">
<nav class="bar bar-tab">
  <a class="tab-item" id="groups-nav" href="{{pathFor 'groupsList'}}">
    <span class="icon icon-star-filled"></span>
    <span class="tab-label">Groups</span>
  </a>
  <a class="tab-item active" id="games-nav" href="{{pathFor 'locationSet'}}">
    <span class="icon icon-list"></span>
    <span class="tab-label">Games</span>
  </a>
<!-- more code -->
</template>
```

The pathFor 'groupsList' works on desktop, but not on mobile. You can try it out here: pp-groups.meteor.com.

This is a prototype only and doesn't use any real data. All of my views code is available here: https://github.com/stewartmccoy/pp-groups/tree/master/groups/client/views

These are my defined routes:

```js
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('layout', {
    path: '/',
    template: 'getLocation',
    layoutTemplate: 'getLocation',
    yieldTemplates: {
      'tabNav': {to: 'footer'}
    }
  });

  this.route('locationSet', {
    path: '/locationSet',
    template: 'locationSet',
    layoutTemplate: 'locationSet'
  });

  this.route('groupsList', {
    path: '/groupsList',
    template: 'groupsList',
    layoutTemplate: 'groupsList'
  });
});
```

Why doesn't the pathFor work on mobile? (It at least doesn't work in Xcode iOS simulator or on iPhone Mobile Safari or Chrome).

Comment: which mobile browser(s) are we talking about?

Comment: @ChristianFritz it doesn't work in Xcode iOS simulator or on iPhone Mobile Safari or Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Routing issue:

Removing the `ratchet` package fixed it for me. Looks like ratchet uses it's own way of linking between templates which is incompatible with `iron-router`. Removing ratchet removes the UI elements, but the routing works on mobile: http://pp-groups-fixed.meteor.com. You could use a strictly UI library, like bootstrap to make the UI elements, or maybe even just the ratchet's UI components. If you want to fully use ratchet, you will most likely have to forgo IronRouter.

### Other things to fix:

#### Layout Templates

When using meteor and iron-router, a *layout template* is a template with common elements, with a `{{> yield}}` placed where you want the regular templates to show up.

You actually only have one real layout template in your code, in `groups.html` there is a layout template named `layout`, and it is unused.

In your code, regular templates are being misused as layout templates, because they don't have `{{> yield}}` in them. Also, the tabNav template is being placed using iron-router, yet you have already included it in each template with `{{> tabNav}}`.

So, you can simply get rid of the layout template code in your iron router, and your app will still function:

```js
Router.map(function() {

  this.route('layout', {
    path: '/',
    template: 'getLocation',
    // layoutTemplate: 'getLocation',
    // yieldTemplates: {
    //   'tabNav': {to: 'footer'}
    // }
  });

  this.route('locationSet', {
    path: '/locationSet',
    template: 'locationSet',
    // layoutTemplate: 'locationSet'
  });

  this.route('groupsList', {
    path: '/groupsList',
    template: 'groupsList',
    // layoutTemplate: 'groupsList'
  });
});
```

A better way is to take out all the common code, the header, general structure of the page, tab bar, and put it in a layout template. Add a `{{> yield}}` where you want the page template to render. Refer to *this* layout template in your router as `layoutTemplate`.

Another sidenote, `iron-router` automatically looks for the template with the same name as the route, if no template is defined. So if you are writing `this.route('groupsList', ...` you don't need to write `template: 'groupsList'` as well.

#### Data

Your `past-game.js` file should be named `get-location.js`. Yes, the name itself doesn't matter, but that is getLocation's complimentary code, not postGame's. Same with `scheduled-games.js` and `locationSet`. Look at the Template.*templateName*.helpers to see how the code corresponds.

Of course, ideally this data should be in a collection. For now, instead of creating the data as arrays with `var`, you could create a seperate file with your data as global variables. Simply define as `PastGames = [...]`, then use the template helpers to return the data you need.

Answer (score 2):

The push.js component is causing the issue. You can still use Rachet with Iron Router by disabling push.js. Per rachet's documention you can disable push by adding a `data-ignore` tag to your HTML link.

```
<!-- Use data-ignore="push" to prevent the push.js interception -->
<a href="http://www.google.com" data-ignore="push">Google<a>
```